# Nativescript Get Current Page

Tags: nativescript

How can I get the current screen I'm working on? For example, I have a slidedrawer containing buttons to navigate to another page. When I'm on a certain page(About Page) and when I tap the button to navigate to the About Page, I want to just close the slidedrawer if it is on the same page.

My idea is that to get the current page and just compare it but I dont know how.

Note: The slidedrawer content menu is a custom component.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem.  The easiest is to install the nativescript-dom plugin and then you can do this really simply:

```
// This will return an array of elements that are SlideDrawer's.
var slideDrawers = getElementsByTagName('SlideDrawer');
```

or even better is if you have assigned your SlideDrawer an id, you can do

```
<!-- Declarative XML -->  
<SlideDrawer id="myId">...</SlideDrawer>

// JS: Will return a single element that matching the id.
var mySlideDrawer = getElementById('myId');
```

However, if you just want to not use any helpers and you want to get direct access to the currentPage the method is to do:

```
var frame = require('ui/frame');
var myPage = frame.topmost().currentPage;
```

Please note; the currentPage will reflect the old page while navigation is taking effect until the navigatedTo event is fired, at that point the currentPage is actually updated to be the currentPage.  However, if you are looking for the current page during any of the navigation events (**NavigatingTo, NavigatedTo, Loaded, Unloaded**) each of those events are transferred a parameter with the current page as part of the object.

```
exports.onNavigatedTo = function(args) {
  var page = args.object;
  // do what you want with the current page variable
}
```